# how to conver date string from one format to another format in c#?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have date string like mydate = "24-Jun-2011";
I want to convert it to another format "2011-06-24".
What is the simple way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way is to parse the string to a DateTime and then convert it to a string again.

Be sure to have a look at the documentation for [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) and [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)

`DateTime.Parse(myDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("24-Jun-2011", "dd-MMM-yyyy").ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

See formats [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

U can `Parse` it to `DateTime` and then using `tostring` + special format get what u need

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/
has a lot of different formatting options...  This should work well for you.